# Can osql.exe or sqlcmd.exe be used to change the default password policy of instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can osql.exe or sqlcmd.exe be used to change password policy of instance?  I have a batch script that creates databases and users but , as you know, the "sp_addlogin" stored procedure doesn't seem to have an option to allow less than 8 char passwords when creating the user.  **How can I use a batch script, calling osql, to lower this policy requirement before using "sp_addlogin" to create the login?**

Here is how I do it so far:

```
-- CREATE USER 2005/2008 sql generated from batch file
-- where username and db name are the same
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.dbo.syslogins WHERE loginname = N'teee') 
BEGIN 
  declare @loginlang nvarchar(132) 
  SELECT @loginlang = N'us_english' 
  IF @loginlang IS NULL OR (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.dbo.syslanguages WHERE name = @loginlang) and @loginlang != N'us_english') 
    SELECT @loginlang = @@language 
 EXEC sp_addlogin N'teee', N'PassMe', N'TEEE', @loginlang 
 ALTER LOGIN teee WITH PASSWORD = 'PassMe' UNLOCK, CHECK_POLICY = OFF, CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF 
END 
GO 
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysusers WHERE name = N'teee' and status != 0) 
EXEC sp_grantdbaccess N'teee', N'teee' 
GO 
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'teee' 
GO 
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'teee' 
GO 
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'teee' 
GO
```

The error I get when I run this is:

```
Msg 15116, Level 16, State 1, Server U0163499, Line 1
Password validation failed. The password does not meet Windows policy requirements because it is too short.
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Server U0163499, Line 10
Cannot alter the login 'teee', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

Obviously, if I use a password greater than or equal to 8 characters when creating the user, it works fine.  I need a solution that also works on SQL 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your Code**

```
 EXEC sp_addlogin N'teee', N'PassMe', N'TEEE', @loginlang 
 ALTER LOGIN teee WITH PASSWORD = 'PassMe' UNLOCK, CHECK_POLICY = OFF,
 CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF
```

**Replace with above line with Below line:**

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [teee] WITH PASSWORD=N'PassMe', 
DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
```

**This code work for me**

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.dbo.syslogins WHERE loginname = N'teee') 
BEGIN 
  declare @loginlang nvarchar(132) 
  SELECT @loginlang = N'us_english' 
  IF @loginlang IS NULL OR (NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM master.dbo.syslanguages WHERE name = @loginlang)
   and @loginlang != N'us_english') 
    SELECT @loginlang = @@language 

 --EXEC sp_addlogin N'teee', N'PassMe', N'TEEE', @loginlang 
 --ALTER LOGIN teee WITH PASSWORD = 'PassMe' UNLOCK,
 --CHECK_POLICY = OFF, CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF 

 CREATE LOGIN [teee] WITH PASSWORD=N'PassMe', 
 DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
END 
GO 
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysusers WHERE name = N'teee' and status != 0) 
EXEC sp_grantdbaccess N'teee', N'teee' 
GO 
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'teee' 
GO 
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'teee' 
GO 
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'teee'
```

GO

Comment: I am not convinced that solution will also work on SQL 2012. I dont believe "CREATE USER" works on SQL2012 any longer, which is why I was forced to use the stored procedure version (because it works on both 2008 and 2012). Am I incorrect?

Comment: i have test 'tsql` on the MSSQL 2012 box using SSMS. Osql.exe does not work with 2012 but sqlcmd will work. did you try it with SSMS on your box? if you then what the error?

Comment: You were right.  It does work.  I just needed to test through the scenario.  Thanks very much.

Comment: We can just use CHECK_POLICY=OFF with Create Login. But not tested with 2012.`CREATE LOGIN ea WITH PASSWORD = 'ea' ,CHECK_POLICY=OFF`